# The datediff function requires 3 argument(s)

Tags: marketing-cloud, error

We have been working on this query for a while and can't understand what the error means that we are getting. The error is "The datediff function requires 3 argument(s)"

```
SELECT 
a.nihrm__BookingContact__c as BOOKING_CONTACT, 
a.Name as ACCOUNT_NAME, 
b.Email as EMAIL, 
b.FirstName as FIRST_NAME, 
b.LastName as LAST_NAME, 
c.FirstName as BOOKING_OWNER_FIRST_NAME, 
c.LastName as BOOKING_OWNER_LAST_NAME 
FROM nihrm__Booking__c_Salesforce a 
JOIN Contact_Salesforce b 
ON a.Id = b.Id 
JOIN User_Salesforce c 
ON a.Id = c.Id 
WHERE a.nihrm__BookingStatus__c = 'Definite' 
AND a.nihrm__BookingTypeName__c = 'Group'
AND a.nihrm__DepartureDate__c >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE(),0)) 
AND a.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM nihrm__Booking__c_Salesforce WHERE Date > dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE(),0)))
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is a basic SQL error, not something specific to marketing cloud - when you use datediff function, set it up so it has three arguments, in plain english, three items inside the brackets: `datediff(a,b,c)` as opposed to your `datediff(day,1,GETDATE(),0)` where you specify four items (`day`, `1`, `GetDate()` and `0`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000821/datediff-function-in-t-sql and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 to understand what goes where.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misplaced closing parenthesis

If you break out your `NOT IN` statement, it looks like:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM nihrm__Booking__c_Salesforce 
WHERE Date > 
dateadd(
    day,
    datediff(
        day,
        1,
        GETDATE(),
        0
    )
)
```

Which makes datediff have 4 parameters and dateadd have 2.

Should likely instead be:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM nihrm__Booking__c_Salesforce 
WHERE Date > dateadd(
    day,
    datediff(
        day,
        1,
        GETDATE()
    ),
    0
    )
)
```

With the closing datediff parenthesis before the 0.